# Displayed url in Iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Have small requirement, Have one iframe and followed by 3 buttons.
Once we click on button1 the url should be displayed in the iframe, same as second button.
Here is my code,Could you please help.

```
function testCoverage(){    
     window.frames['idIfrm'].document.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }
function testCoverage1(){   
    window.frames['idIfrm'].document.location.href = 'http://yahoo.com';
}
```

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw4VW/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code, it is working fine in my end,

```
<div>
    <button><a href="http://www.computerhope.com/banners/banner.gif" target="iframe_a">Banner1</a></button>
    <button><a href="http://www.computerhope.com/banners/banner2.gif" target="iframe_a">Banner2</a></button>
    <button><a href="http://www.computerhope.com/banners/banner3.gif" target="iframe_a" onclick="closeWindow();">Banner3</a></button>
    <div>       
    <iframe src="http://www.computerhope.com/banners/banner3.gif" name="iframe_a" width="900" height="350px" id="iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;">
    </iframe>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your fiddle does not run since it is set up to run the JavaScript onload and not in the head. Change the dropdown on the top left.

[image]

Second issue, you should be setting the source of the iframe, not the document location.

```
window.frames['idIfrm'].src = "foo.html";
```

Third issue which you can not do anything about is Google and Yahoo can not be put into the iframe. You will get the error

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the src attribute. your code should look like this

```
    function testCoverage(){
       document.getElementById['idIfrm'].src = 'http://google.com';
    }
    function testCoverage1(){   
       document.getElementById['idIfrm'].src = 'http://yahoo.com';
    }
```